# How to add sequence row numbers based on column values SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, function, sequence, partition, row-number

I have the following table in SQL Server;

```
DesiredRowNo. Customer  Date        NID                 SID     Contacts  AG
 1               AAA    04/09/2018  15357989260016600   100743  1          1
 1               AAA    04/09/2018  15358110980018300   100743  1          1
 1               AAA    04/09/2018  15358197620012800   100743  1          1
 2               AAA    21/09/2018  15358902310016400   100743  1          1
 2               AAA    21/09/2018  15358999300015200   100743  1          1
 3               AAA    29/09/2018  15359624190012200   100743  1          1
 3               AAA    29/09/2018  15359896100010500   100702  1          1
 4               AAA    30/09/2018  15360551640011900   100743  1          1
 1               BBB    05/09/2018  15357989260016600   100743  1          1
 1               BBB    05/09/2018  15358110980018300   100743  1          1
 2               BBB    08/09/2018  15358197620012800   100743  1          1
 3               BBB    15/09/2018  15358902310016400   100743  1          1
 3               BBB    15/09/2018  15358999300015200   100743  1          1
 4               BBB    19/09/2018  15359624190012200   100743  1          1
 5               BBB    24/09/2018  15359896100010500   100702  1          1
 5               BBB    24/09/2018  15360551640011900   100743  1          1
```

I need the 1st column (DesiredRowNo.) to display a rank/row number based on the customer and the date. So for **Customer AAA**, all the rows with **same date ranked as 1**, then the **next unique date ranked as 2**, and so on. (has to be sequential based on date)

See the **DesiredRowNo.** values above for a better explanation as to what I'm trying to achieve.

Ive tried using;

```
ROW_NUMER() over (partition by Customer, date order by date)
```

But this doesnt seem to give the correct sequencing as required.

Any ideas?

Comment: If you partition by date and order by it, what order are you expecting other than random (if you were asked to place 3 dates in order, and they were all the same date, would you know which is the "correct" order without more detail)? You need to order by a different column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ooops, this was a massive oversight. Ive fixed it using this:

```
DENSE_RANK() over (partition by Customer order by date)
```

Thanks for your steer Larnu

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
 select  tab.DesiresRowNo.,final.Customer,
final.NID,final.SID,final.Contacts,final.AG
 from Table final
 left join 
 ( select
 ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Customer ASC) AS DesiresRowNo.,
 Customer,Date
 from Table
 group by Customer,Date )tab
 on final.Customer=tab.Customer
 and final.Date=tab.Date
```